# Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

anyone can help me, the id that I called could not be found , I'm new in codeigniter and php, and am trying to create crud (update) how to solve this? thanks in advance

Controller

```
    public function editdata($id) ---------> LINE 41
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Edit Data Interview';
        $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
        $data['form1'] = $this->db->get_where('form1', ['id_form1' => $id])->row_array();

    }
```

View

```
    <form action="<?= site_url('datainterview/editdata/' . $m['id_form1']) ?>" method="post">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="id_form1" value="<?= $m['id_form1'] ?>">
                                            <button onclick="return confirm('Edit Data ?')" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</button>
                                        </form>
```

Error

```
    Message: Too few arguments to function DataInterview::editdata(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\MYNET\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\MYNET\application\controllers\DataInterview.php

Line Number: 41
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically your url does not contain the id when you submit your data.

If that is a required param to perform your action that error is a good thing. If that is not a required param then you should give it a default value.

```
    public function editdata($id = null)
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Edit Data Interview';
        $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
        $data['form1'] = $this->db->get_where('form1', ['id_form1' => $id])->row_array();

    }
```

This way the id has the default value of null. So if you try to access that variable that would be the value you get when you access:

example.com/DataInterview/editdata

However when you access:

example.com/DataInterview/editdata/12

you get the value of 12.

You might even go a step forward and give a proper error when the id is not sent into the function. Something like:

```
public function editdata($id = null)
{
    if (is_null($id)) {
       show_404();
    }
    $data['title'] = 'Edit Data Interview';
    $data['user'] = $this->db->get_where('user', ['email' => $this->session->userdata('email')])->row_array();
    $data['form1'] = $this->db->get_where('form1', ['id_form1' => $id])->row_array();

}
```

Then you can get to that error flashdata and show proper errors to your user.